# Updating csv file with specefic structure in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime

Im doing some tests with spectrometer and want to create an updating csv file containing the results in python.  im using pandas and the loop is working great, i was able to creat an updating file but im pretty new to python, and getting hard time creating this specific structure:

the first column will be the date and the local time with an empty cell in the first value.
the first row ( starting from the second cell) will be a constant vector. ==> only first row.
the second row and all others ( the first value will start from the second cell -  first containing the date ) will be variable.

I need help defining this structure and conditions

The result of the code should shown in ecxel as the  example picture
(in the example there is only time, but  i do need times and dates)
picture in ecxel for reference

Thanks alot!
yuval

code:

```
time_tuple=logging.time.localtime()
time_string=time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S", time_tuple)
fields=['wave length','intensity']
with open(name, 'a') as f:
    write=csv.writer(f)
    write.writerow(time_string)
    write.writerow(fields)
    write.writerows(data)
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dk0uk.jpg)picture in ecxel for reference

[csv file that created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ju6H.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry, but it's unclear what your question is. Do you want to convert existing csv data? Then we need the csv structure of the input file. You mention "conditions" but don't specify them, are you running into an issue in your code? Then post that code.

Comment: Hey Nate , no I’m looking for the right code to create/ write csv file with the structure I wrote , that shown in excel as the picture

Comment: Any suggestions? You can view the code and the csv that created